# Let $P$ be a real polynomial of degree at least three, split on $\mathbb R$. Show that every multiple root of $P'$ is a root of $P$

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, roots

> Let $P$ be a real polynomial of degree at least three, split on $\mathbb R$.
>
> Show that every multiple root of $P'$ is a root of $P$.

It is unusual to consider the roots of P'. I would process by induction on the degree of $P$ but it is not clear..

Comment: What does split on R mean?

Comment: If its degree is n, P has n real roots counted with multiplicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_1\le x_2\le\cdots\le x_n$ be the zeros of $P$. We count these
with multiplicity, so a zero of order $k$ appears $k$ times. By Rolle's
theorem and the fact that an order $k$ zero of $P$ is an
order $k-1$ zero of $P'$, the zeros of $P'$ are $y_1,\ldots,y_{n-1}$
with $x_1\le y_1\le x_2\le y_2\le\cdots\le y_{n-1}\le x_n$.

So, what if $y_i=y_{i+1}$?